# Automatically working out the average of filtered results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where column P has a score between 1-6

The cell O4 has the following formula: =AVERAGEIFS(P8:P5000,P8:P5000,"<>6",P8:P5000,"<>0")

This formula searches for the average of the score in column P excluding 6, blanks and 0

Column O has staff names e.g John, Mark, Tim.......

What i want to do is for Cell O4 to automatically calculate the average of the figures shown in column P after i have used the filter function to show only results of a selected staff member.

I was hoping excel might be able to do this automatically however cell O4 appears to still be showing the average of the whole column P regardless of whether i have filtered or not.

I was given the formula below on another forum but it seems to be giving slightly wrong results albeit only by a small amount but i need to have the results exact if possible. Any help appreciated.

=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(P8:P100,{0,6},0)),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(P8,ROW(P8:P100)-ROW(P8),0,1)))/SUMPRODUCT(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(P8:P100,{0,6},0)),SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(P8,ROW(P8:P100)-ROW(P8),0,1)))

Comment: I get the same results with your formula and Axel's suggestion - dumb question but your version only goes to row 100, I assume you've adjusted that to cover the whole data range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

`{=AVERAGE(IF((P8:P5000<>6)*(P8:P5000<>0)*SUBTOTAL(103,INDIRECT("O"&ROW(8:5000))),P8:P5000))}`

will do what you want. Assuming the Filter is on column O.

The 103 in SUBTOTAL will also exclude if rows are manually hidden. If this ist unwanted and it should only exclude hidden rows, if filtered, then use 3 instead.

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to create the array formula.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate table in a new sheet with all unique staff members and then perform the calculation.  This way, you can quickly compare values for all staff just by scanning the table instead of having to constantly update the filter to see the values for potentially dozens or hundreds of staff.  You would add the staff name range and criteria to your AVERAGEIFS formula.

For your example:

```
Sheet 2

        A           B   
        ---         --- 
1   |   Staff       Average             
2   |   Bob         =AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,Sheet1!$O$8:$O$5000,A2,Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,"<>6",Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,"<>0")
3   |   Mary        =AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,Sheet1!$O$8:$O$5000,A3,Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,"<>6",Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,"<>0")
4   |   Joe         =AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,Sheet1!$O$8:$O$5000,A4,Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,"<>6",Sheet1!$P$8:$P$5000,"<>0")
```